# Knockout click binding in popover html content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

I am trying to apply the click binding in HTML contain on the popover.
The click event is not working in the **$root.confirmDeleteColor**

Below is the html code and in the button(YES) the click event is called.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: responseData">
    <td align="center">
       <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Color" data-bind="attr: { id: id}"></a>
       <a class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash popover-top" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" 
       data-content='<div><b>Are you Sure you want to delete this Item ?</b><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">No</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.confirmDeleteColor">yes</button></div></div>'
       title="Delete Color"></a>
    </td>
</tbody>
```

Here is the VM code

```
confirmDeleteColor: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log("testing");
}
```

In the console the testing text is not printed.

Here is the image of the page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because when bootstrap is appending popover to the DOM - knockout template is already compiled, so Knockout doesn't know about your click binding.
In such cases you should use bindings like this one:
[Knockstrap popover](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#popover)
Or create your own ([Custom Knockout bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html))

Comment: I don't want to use the library. I want to perform with the custom knockout bindings can you please show me an example